# need improvement for my javascript code function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating a function that seems to work well but I need improvement if someone can help me

> `expected result: 
>      const x = ['i','like','js']
>      given => ['i','i-like','i-like-js']`

```js
function myFunction(parrams) {
  const arr = []
  for (let index = 0; index < parrams.length; index++) {
    const x = parrams.indexOf(parrams[index])
    if (x != 0) {
      arr.push(parrams.slice(0, x).join('-'))
    }
    if (x === parrams.length - 1) {
      arr.push(parrams.slice(0, x + 1).join('-'))
    }
  }
  return arr
}

const arrayTest = ['need','improvement','for','my','code']

console.log(myFunction(arrayTest))
```

Comment: Maybe better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you know Object Oriented Programming then try OOP in javascript will improve your code quality and reduce code smell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `x` is same as index, you can avoid that. Also made some modifications as well. Please check.

```js
function myFunction(parrams) {
  const arr = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < parrams.length; index++) {
      arr.push(parrams.slice(0, index + 1).join("-"));
  }
  return arr;
}
const arrayTest = ["need", "improvement", "for", "my", "code"];
console.log(myFunction(arrayTest));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using `Array.prototype.map`, might not be the fastest, but short enough

```js
const arrayTest = ["need", "improvement", "for", "my", "code"];
const result = arrayTest.map((_, i, arr) => arr.slice(0, i + 1).join('-'));

console.log(result);
```